# EmEditor - How to navigate to the next difference when doing a file compare

Tags: compare, emeditor

I am using EmEditor to compare two 2.8 GB files and cannot for the life of me figure out how to navigate from one line to the next were differences exist between the two files. There are almost 8 million rows, so scrolling or paging down to find the next highlighted line would be incredibly painful.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To go to the next change, select `Next Change` on the `Compare` menu, or press <kbd>F7</kbd>.  To go to the previous change, select `Previous Change` on the `Compare` menu, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Yutaka!  All set now.